# export c4d mesh

Tags: export

I am trying to export a mesh and his textures out of c4d. The mesh is a car that have multiple materials and multiple objects. It looks like this :

[image: original mesh]

For straightforwardness reasons I would like to have only 1 mesh file, and 1 texture file after the export. Export the mesh is the easy part, I just have to connect every objects that compose the mesh and export is in the format I want. But I have problems with textures. After some research I found that I had to use the "Bake Object" tool. So after setting the texture size ( 2048x2048 ) and file format, I get this result with the single texture :

[image: my mesh]

I'm not a big user of c4d. I just use it to convert objects and reduce objects numbers/merge textures, so I have no idea where the problem can be... I tried options like "keep uvs", that didn't worked. Since the connected object looks like the first image, the problem should be in the second part.

Is there a simpler way of doing that?

Comment: Looks like a problem with normals to me. I don't know anything at all about c4d, but if there's a button to recalculate normals or something similar, I recommend trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the phong angle on the model, optimize points(Mesh -> Commands -> Optimize) and increase resolution of texture on material using the editor tag.